# Runtime error in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i made email form which works on localhost however after uploading it on server it coming like this message on page

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: So why don;t you do what it tells you to do?

Comment: you have either to run the page on a local browser(on the server) or enable errors and debug your code then uneable it again (in web.config).
if its an email form be sure that your SMTP configuration and cardentials are correct

Answer (score 0):

Two simple ways to see what might be causing the error. You can...

A) follow the instructions it gives you and enable the webpage to show the error through the webconfig.

B) Remote desktop connect to the web server and use it's browser. If you connect to the site from the server itself, it will also show the full error.

be warned - The first option can be a security problem. It does not discriminate who it shows errors to. If you keep this enabled it can reveal the inner working of your site to people you may not want seeing it.